# GRE results by graduating institution

Tags: education

To be clear, what I have in mind is the average GRE scores of students who have graduated from, or are attending a college and have taken the GRE (for whatever reason); data like:

- U.C. Berkeley  700
- MIT          691

I contacted the GRE about a year ago and they do not seem to have this data (at least, not for public consumption)

Asking here based on the slim chance that this is available through some other source.

Comment: I think if you have paid subscription to the https://secure.usnews.com/commerce/checkout/college-compass-with-digital?src=login then you may have access to this sort of information.

Comment: @Sislam Thank you, I will investigate this and ask my institution to pay the fee if the data is available (they probably will not :)).